# How to get a value of float [numerical] from a series float in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

```
i-need-number-value-this-series = security(syminfotickerid, _res, ta.sma(close,20))

test-operation = test-function () - i-need-number-value-this-series
```

I need number of float in this value doesn't need float series?

How can get a value from this series for operation?